# VB.net Prevent Listbox delete error catching

Tags: vb.net

I got 2 list boxes and using a button to remove each item in the list box. Uses the index of the first listbox to delete second listbox. Problem is that when there is no item selected an error occurs.

```
If ListBox1.SelectedItem = -1 Then
Exit Sub
Else
ListBox2.Items.RemoveAt(ListBox1.SelectedIndex)
ListBox1.Items.Remove(ListBox1.SelectedItem)
Calculate()
End If
```

It supposed to stop if Selected item is -1 (No item selected) To stop the operation.

Comment: `If ListBox.SelectedItems.Count > 0 then....`

Comment: By the way, it appears that those `ListBoxes` are supposed to be related by item index so I would suggest that you create a single list that contains both data items and actually bind it to both `ListBoxes`, just using a different `DisplayMember` in each case.  You can then simply remove the selected item from the underlying list and it will automatically disappear from both `ListBoxes`.

Comment: @jmcilhinney haha this is just a school project so i got no clue how to do that. Maybe some example code?

Comment: This is not really an appropriate for that because it has nothing really to do with this question, hence I posted it in a comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If no item is selected then `SelectedItem`, which is what you're testing, will be `Nothing`.  It's `SelectedIndex` that will be -1.

Also, don't use an `If...Else` if you only want to do something in one case.  Just invert the condition:

```
If ListBox1.SelectedIndex <> -1 Then
    ListBox2.Items.RemoveAt(ListBox1.SelectedIndex)
    ListBox1.Items.Remove(ListBox1.SelectedItem)
    Calculate()
End If
```